# What does `layer.get_weights()` return?

Tags: python, keras

I'm using Keras to do some experiments and I just monitored the weight update for a simple mlp model:

```
# model contains one input layer in the format of dense, 
# one hidden layer and one output layer.
model=mlp() 
weight_origin=model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(.....) # with adam optimizer
weight_updated=model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
print weight_origin-weight_updated
```

For the first dense layer, I got a matrix of zeros. I thought the training doesn't change this weight. However, weights in other layers are changed. So I'm confused, why the first layer is unchanged? 
I checked the source code but still got no answer, then I tried monitoring:

```
model.layers[0].get_weights()[1] # get_weight() returns a list of weights
```

This time, the weights did change. So I'm wondering which weight is the "true" weight that does working during training? Why there are two elements in the weight list?

---

Definition of `mlp()`:

```
def mlp():
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(500, input_dim=784))
    model.add(Dense(503,init='normal',activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(503,init='normal',activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    return model
```

Comment: Could you provide us the mlp() function? This is really weird behaviour

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I've updated it. I'm confused on the second weight in `layer.weights` list.

Comment: Have you compiled your model?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko yes, sorry for my careless

Comment: @LudwigZhou How long do you train before comparing both matrices?

Comment: @nemo I ran 3 epochs for whole MNIST training data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the question of `layer.get_weights()`:

I ran some tests on this issue and checked the source codes. I found that the `Dense` layer is a subclass of `Layer` and its weights, which is a type of python `list` has two elements weight of the layer stored at `layer.get_weights()[0]` and the **`bias`** is stored at `layer.get_weights()[1]`.

There's one thing to note that, `bias` can be disabled during defining the layer: `model.add(Dense(503,init='normal',activation='relu',`**`bias=False`**`))`. In that case, the list `layer.get_weights()` has only one element. If you set the `bias` attribute as `False` after defining it, there will still be an element for `bias` and it would be updated after you fitting the model.

For the question of **not updating**:

I set up a **Sequential** model with only one dense layer:

`def mlp_2():
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=784, activation='softmax', bias =False))
    return model`

Then I use the same way above to compile and fit it. This is what I got:

[image]

It still seems not update the weight, however, we can tell the weight is definately changed. Because the accuracy is increasing. I think the only explanation is updates on the first `dense` layer (which you define `input_dim`) is too small for Keras to printout. I didn't check the more precise value of the weights, it would be great if someone could confrim it.

Comment: great explanation!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example.

```
import numpy as np
from  keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten

X_train=np.random.rand(1,10)
Y_train=2*X_train
input_dim = X_train.shape[1]
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=10))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
weight_origin_0=model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
weight_origin_1=model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=1, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1)
print(weight_origin_0-model.layers[0].get_weights()[0])  #the first layer
print(weight_origin_1-model.layers[1].get_weights()[0])  #the second layer
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to see exactly how the values of all weights and biases are changing over time. You can can use the Keras callback method which can be used to record the weights values at each training epoch. Using a model like this for example,

```
import numpy as np
model = Sequential([Dense(16, input_shape=(train_inp_s.shape[1:])), Dense(12), Dense(6), Dense(1)])
```

add the callbacks **kwarg during fitting:

```
gw = GetWeights()
model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.15, epochs=10, batch_size=100, callbacks=[gw])
```

where the callback is defined by

```
class GetWeights(Callback):
    # Keras callback which collects values of weights and biases at each epoch
    def __init__(self):
        super(GetWeights, self).__init__()
        self.weight_dict = {}

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        # this function runs at the end of each epoch

        # loop over each layer and get weights and biases
        for layer_i in range(len(self.model.layers)):
            w = self.model.layers[layer_i].get_weights()[0]
            b = self.model.layers[layer_i].get_weights()[1]
            print('Layer %s has weights of shape %s and biases of shape %s' %(
                layer_i, np.shape(w), np.shape(b)))

            # save all weights and biases inside a dictionary
            if epoch == 0:
                # create array to hold weights and biases
                self.weight_dict['w_'+str(layer_i+1)] = w
                self.weight_dict['b_'+str(layer_i+1)] = b
            else:
                # append new weights to previously-created weights array
                self.weight_dict['w_'+str(layer_i+1)] = np.dstack(
                    (self.weight_dict['w_'+str(layer_i+1)], w))
                # append new weights to previously-created weights array
                self.weight_dict['b_'+str(layer_i+1)] = np.dstack(
                    (self.weight_dict['b_'+str(layer_i+1)], b))
```

This callback builds a dictionary with all the layer weights and biases, labeled by the layer numbers, so you can see how they are changing over time as your model is being trained. You'll notice that the shape of each weight and bias array depends on the shape of the model layer. One weights array and one bias array are saved for each layer in your model. The third axis (depth) shows their evolution over time.

Here we used 10 epochs and a model with layers of 16, 12, 6, and 1 neurons:

```
for key in gw.weight_dict:
    print(str(key) + ' shape: %s' %str(np.shape(gw.weight_dict[key])))

w_1 shape: (5, 16, 10)
b_1 shape: (1, 16, 10)
w_2 shape: (16, 12, 10)
b_2 shape: (1, 12, 10)
w_3 shape: (12, 6, 10)
b_3 shape: (1, 6, 10)
w_4 shape: (6, 1, 10)
b_4 shape: (1, 1, 10)
```

Comment: i think this would not be true if you get a batch_norm or drop out layer, which also have trainable weights